# `dtrt-indent-mode` erroneously uses Tab characters

Tags: indentation, tabs

Here is an example file (`/tmp/asdf.sh`), for which I want `dtrt-indent-mode` to do the right thing.

```
#! /usr/bin/env bash

function asdf()
{
    printf "asASDFASDF"
    echo "1234"
}

printf "qwerqwerqwer\n"
result=$(asdf)

if [ df ] ; then
    if [ er ] ; then
        wefwefew
    fi
fi
```

I have created a minimal Emacs init file (`~/tmp/basic-init.el`) to test this:

```
(require 'package)
(setq package-enable-at-startup nil)
(add-to-list 'package-archives '("melpa" . "http://melpa.org/packages/"))
(add-to-list 'package-archives '("gnu" . "http://elpa.gnu.org/packages/"))
(add-to-list 'package-archives '("melpamilk" . "http://melpa.milkbox.net/packages/"))
(package-initialize)

(unless package-archive-contents
  (package-refresh-contents))
(unless (package-installed-p 'use-package)
  (package-install 'use-package))
(require 'use-package)

(defun my-prog-mode-hook ()
  (dtrt-indent-mode))

(use-package dtrt-indent
  :ensure t
  :config (dtrt-indent-mode t))

(use-package blank-mode
  :ensure t)
(global-set-key (kbd "C-c b") 'blank-mode)
```

Starting emacs with that init file, opening that shell file:

```
emacs -q -l ~/tmp/basic-init.el /tmp/asdf.sh
```

then showing blank characters with `C-c b`, gives this:

[image]

(Don't mind the yellow highlight, blank-mode should be setup to leave that alone.)

Going to that yellow line, deleting a space char then pressing `TAB` gives this:

[image]

According to me, the right thing to do is not to put a Tab character there.

---

What I have found trying to understand what is going on:

Luckily, `dtrt-indent` has a diagnosis tool. This is the output of `dtrt-indent-diagnosis`, on the original file (no Tab character):

```
Guessing offset for /tmp/asdf.sh

Elapsed time for analysis: 0.001 seconds

Total relevant lines: 5 out of 17 (limit: 5000)

Histogram:

     4x   4 spaces
     1x   8 spaces

Analysis:

  offset 2 works for 100.00% of relevant lines, matching 2 distinct offsets - merged with offset 4 (0.00% deviation, limit 20.00%)
  offset 4 works for 100.00% of relevant lines, matching 2 distinct offsets - CONSIDERED
  offset 8 works for  20.00% of relevant lines, matching 1 distinct offsets - CONSIDERED
  offset 3 works for   0.00% of relevant lines, matching 0 distinct offsets - rejected: too few distinct matching offsets (1 required)
  offset 5 works for   0.00% of relevant lines, matching 0 distinct offsets - rejected: too few distinct matching offsets (1 required)
  offset 6 works for   0.00% of relevant lines, matching 0 distinct offsets - rejected: too few distinct matching offsets (1 required)
  offset 7 works for   0.00% of relevant lines, matching 0 distinct offsets - rejected: too few distinct matching offsets (1 required)

Summary:

  Best guess is offset 4 with 100.00% matching lines (80.00% required)
  Hard tab percentage: 0.00% (0 lines), -100.00% superior to soft tabs (threshold 300.00%)
  Soft tab percentage: 100.00% (5 lines), inf% superior to hard tabs (threshold 300.00%)

Conclusion:

  Guessed offset 4 with 100% confidence.
  Change indent-tab-setting: yes, to nil
```

I did not manage to find help on `indent-tab-setting`.

However, `C-h k` on `TAB` key press gives this:

```
TAB (translated from <tab>) runs the command indent-for-tab-command
(found in global-map), which is an interactive compiled Lisp function
in ‘indent.el’.

It is bound to TAB.

(indent-for-tab-command &optional ARG)

Indent the current line or region, or insert a tab, as appropriate.
This function either inserts a tab, or indents the current line,
or performs symbol completion, depending on ‘tab-always-indent’.
The function called to actually indent the line or insert a tab
is given by the variable ‘indent-line-function’.
```

and `C-h v` on `indent-line-function`:

```
indent-line-function is a variable defined in ‘indent.el’.
Its value is ‘smie-indent-line’
Local in buffer asdf.sh; global value is indent-relative
```

Apparently, `smie-` is a default naive indentation function.

I was expecting to find a `dtrt-` function here.

How can I make `dtrt-indent-mode` do the right thing?

GNU Emacs 26.1.

Comment: "Change indent-tab-setting: yes, to nil" is poorly worded. `dtrt-indent` is recommending that you change the value of `indent-tabs-mode` to nil for that file/buffer, to prevent the insertion of tabs.

Comment: @nega: Please consider posting that as an answer.

Comment: Please post some info (e.g. a link) about what/where `dtrt-indent-mode` is. It doesn't seem to be in vanilla Emacs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I received help from the devs at [github](https://github.com/jscheid/dtrt-indent/issues/59).

Basically, at its default, `dtrt-indent-mode` does nothing if [SMIE](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/SMIE.html) also is active. Even if `dtrt-indent-mode` is active. Activating it (even buffer-locally) always defers to SMIE if active, which it is in many programming language modes.

This deferring can be overridden with `dtrt-indent-run-after-smie`.

Here is the relevant section of the basic init file in the question, modified to activate `dtrt` always:

```
(defun my-prog-mode-hook ()
  (dtrt-indent-mode))

(add-hook 'prog-mode-hook 'my-prog-mode-hook)

(use-package dtrt-indent
  :ensure t
  :config
  (setq dtrt-indent-run-after-smie t) ;; Run even if SMIE is active
  )
```

Answer (score 1):

[dtrt-indent](https://github.com/jscheid/dtrt-indent) is a minor mode that will guess the indentation offset of a file and adjusts those local settings accordingly. It hooks in to several major modes, and works reasonably well.

@Gauthier is wondering why `dtrt-indent` is inserting a TAB character to perform indentation after guessing, with 100% confidence, that the indentation offset is 4 SPACE characters. I have always taken the line in the `dtrt-indent-diagnosis` report to be a recommendation to the user to change the "indent settings" (`indent-tabs-mode`). How the user chooses to do that is up to the user. (File local variables, directory local variables, global configuration, etc). In this case `Change indent-tab-setting: yes, to nil` is saying "Hey, maybe you want to disable `indent-tabs-mode` here. I dunno. You do you."

I believe the reason why @Guathier was able to delete 2 indentation levels of 4 spaces, and insert a single tab character to match those 2 indentation levels is because `indent-tabs-mode` was enabled (`t`). This short example file didn't meet the heuristics required for `dtrt-indent` to change `indent-tabs-mode`. The code in fact states that it may have trouble with small files.

Note that in a comment I stated:

> Oh, also, dtrt-indent only adjusts indent level, it won't change what the indentation is (tabs/spaces). Hence the recommendation on whether or not to change the "indent-tab-settings". – nega 5 hours ago

That comment is incorrect, and I've deleted it. I confirmed I was wrong when I globally set my `indent-tabs-mode` to `nil` and opened a rather large C++ file that was indented with tabs, and `dtrt-indent` locally changed `indent-tabs-mode` to `t`. By default `dtrt-indent` will tell you what it changes in the mini-buffer and `*Messages*` buffer. You can change the verbosity of these messages by customizing `dtrt-indent-verbosity`. Said C++ example reported:

```
Note: c-basic-offset adjusted to 8
Note: indent-tabs-mode adjusted to t
```

I haven't studied the code in depth, but I suspect that this test case, and maybe other examples that @Gauthier has seen just didn't have enough data for `dtrt-indent` to make a decision. Personally, I think that conservatism is a good thing, as I think it would be more jarring to have my indent "things" changed, than just my indent "sizes".

Comment: Could "Change indent-tab-setting" be more clear? Maybe, but that's what github issues are for :)

Comment: If you're discovering `dtrt-indent` for the first time because of this question and you use `use-package`, note that the package is `dtrt-indent` and the function you want to add to your hook is `dtrt-indent-mode`.

Comment: Thanks for the insight, I just noticed the diagnostics says "Change", not "Changed". The documentation says this: "For determining hard vs. soft tabs, dtrt-indent counts the number of lines out of the eligible lines in the fixed segment that are indented using hard tabs, and the number of lines indented using spaces.  If either count is significantly higher than the other count, `indent-tabs-mode' will be modified." Why wouldn't this give me soft tabs?

Comment: Again, maybe because the example was too small for `dtrt-indent` to generate the statistics to make a decision. I don't know. I've studied `dtrt-indent` more to answer your question than I have in the 10+ years of using it. :)

Comment: It shows in the example code, but I noticed it first in much larger files. I'll try and post an issue in github.

Comment: The problem was that `dtrt` won't touch indentation if `SMIE` is active, by default. There is a variable to override that. See my answer.